# How do i flip a number half triangle in c++?

Tags: c++

I need to code this in c++ using nested for loops. [click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXdEv.png)And this is what I have right now.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int i, j, k, n = 9;

  for(i = n; i >= 0; i--){ 

    for(j = i; j >= 0; j--)

     cout << j<<" ";

    cout <<endl;

  }

}
```

how do I flip it.

Comment: Paste your code and input as text, not as image.

Comment: Edit your post.  Highlight the `{}` to format.  Covert from tabs to spaces if necessary.

Comment: You code only outputs spaces, white spaces.  Flipping won't have any visual effect.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It outputs numbers: https://wandbox.org/permlink/YD2ZLBQbtwDjIiTm

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ print triangle star".  There are already a plethora of related questions.

Comment: how do I make the triangle go the other way like the picture because I have looked at those videos and its not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are starting with the longest row and going down. Start with the shortest row and go up:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int n = 9;
  for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){ // start with 0 and go up to n
    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
     std::cout << j << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

To flip in the other direction fill it with spaces:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int n = 9;
  for(int i = n; i >= 0; i--){ 
    for(int j = 2*(n-i); j >= 0; j--) // fill with spaces
      std::cout << ' ';
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) // start with 0 and go up to i
      std::cout << j << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {    // i is 9 and its decrementing over time
        for (int j = 9; j > i; j--) { // j is also 9 and it must be greater than i, otherwise you will have unnecessary one blank space in first row
            cout << "  "; // This is my way of doing things, i would rather print double blank space
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) { // k is just incrementing from 0 to i and it has blank space 
            cout << k << " ";
        }    
        cout << endl;
  } 
}
```